# Help With Understanding Error System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, visualforce, failing-tests

I am new to apex and im trying to do my first deployment of a visual force page.
Im trying to deploy my apex classes and their tests but i'm getting this error below.
I have tried changing the opportunity select statement to a list statement but this did not work.
Any help would be appreciated as im very stuck and struggling to find answers on similar questions on this site.

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
> Stack Trace: Class.CreatePdfController.savePDF: line 6, column 1 Class.CreatePdfControllerTest.savePDFTest: line 34, column 1

Below is my apex class

```java
public with sharing class CreatePdfController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String savePDF(String id) {
        Pagereference pdf = Page.MallQuote;
        pdf.getParameters().put('id', id);     
       opportunity currentopportunity = [
            SELECT Id, Name 
            FROM opportunity 
            WHERE Id =: id
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
        ];
  
      
        List<Attachment> attachList = [
            SELECT Id, ParentId 
            FROM Attachment 
            WHERE ParentId =: id
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
        ];
        Integer count = attachList.size() + 1;

        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        Blob body;
    
        try {
            body = pdf.getContentAsPDF(); 
        }
        catch (VisualforceException e) {
            body = Blob.valueOf('Error body.');
        }
    
        attach.Body = body;
        Datetime dateTimes = Datetime.now();
        String pdfName = '' + currentopportunity.Name + ' report ' + count + '.pdf';
        attach.Name = pdfname;
        attach.IsPrivate = false;
        attach.ParentId = id;
    
        if(Schema.sObjectType.Attachment.isCreateable()) {
            insert attach;
        }

        String resultLink = 'https://' + System.Url.getOrgDomainUrl().getHost() + '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + attach.Id;
        return resultLink;
    }
}
```

And here is my test class

```java
@IsTest
public class CreatePdfControllerTesty {

    public static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = 'The expected amount does not match the received amount.';
    public static final String TEST_NAME = 'Test';
    public static final String LOGO = 'Logo';

    @IsTest
    static void savePDFTest(){
       
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name = TEST_NAME);
        insert testAccount;

        Opportunity newoppo = new Opportunity();
        newoppo.Name = TEST_NAME;
        newoppo.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
        newoppo.StageName = 'Logged';
        newoppo.CloseDate = date.parse('03/03/2022');
        insert newoppo;
        
        
        String pdfLink = CreatePdfController.savePDF(newoppo.Id);
        System.assertNotEquals(null, pdfLink, ERROR_MESSAGE);

        List<Attachment> attachList = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment];
        System.assertEquals(1, attachList.size(), ERROR_MESSAGE);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: 1/2: The only thing that's really jumping out to me is the `with sharing` modifier in your class and the `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` in your queries. You're creating test data to be queried (which is where many people new to testing stumble), so that leads me to believe that the issue is with the profile assigned to your user not having access to the `Opportunity` object. That, or something interesting with your Org-Wide Defaults or sharing settings.

Comment: 2/2: Can you tell us what your assigned profile is in the org you're trying to deploy to? It is a standard profile? Also, in your profile, go to "Object Settings",  find and click "Opportunities", and tell us what you see for "Object Permissions".

Comment: It is probably the line `opportunity currentopportunity = ...` with either a non-existant ID or where the user does not have sharing or permission access as Derek F has suggested. Unfortunately the assignment of an SOQL query result to a single record only works if there is exactly one record in the result. An empty query result gives the error you are getting instead of assigning null as you might expect.